# Can I use Intel RST caching on another (i.e. non-OS) hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, cache

Is it possible to cache a (non-OS) HDD with an SSD in RST?

I used RST to create a regular RAID volume of 128GB (I had to put the SSD and the HDD in RAID because RST requires it).

I want to configure it so that the HDD uses teh SSD as its cache.

Hardware:

- ASUS P8Z68-V PRO GEN3
- 128 GB M4-CT128 M4SSD2 SCSI Disk Device (OS drive)
- 64 GB M4-CT128 M4SSD2
- 2 TB HDD

Comment: What chipset are you using? What motherboard? Exactly what steps did you take in attempting to enable the SSD caching?

Comment: asus p8z68-v pro/gen3
i connect my 128g to the marvell controller and the 64G+2T to the intel controller,installed the os on the 128,install RST,change the intel controller to raid,tryed to create from the 64 and the 2T the cached partion,got 128G pration,and not 2T...

Comment: Ahh, I just realized, you're only trying to cache a single rotating HDD.  I don't believe that's a supported option, as the intention is caching of RAIDs (like 2 1TB drives in a RAID1 or 0)

Comment: That is not correct, Intel Smart Response Technology works perfectly fine with just one SSD and one HDD. My system is configured exactly this way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you're doing it wrong, you're gonna have to delete the array. 
Don't create a RAID array, just set the controller as RAID, boot normally and open the Intel Storage Technology control panel.

Go to Accelerate, select enable acceleration and select your 2TB drive, that's all that there's to it. It will create the Array automatically