# Caching a Non-OS HDD

Tags: windows, ssd, cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use Intel RST caching on another (i.e. non-OS) hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/522793/can-i-use-intel-rst-caching-on-another-i-e-non-os-hard-drive)

Is it possible to cache a non-OS HDD with an SSD in RST?

I put the HDD and the SSD in RAID-0, and the RST creating a regular RAID volume of 128GB.

Hardware:

- ASUS P8Z68-V PRO GEN3
- 128 GB M4-CT128 M4SSD2 SCSI Disk Device (OS drive)
- 64 GB M4-CT128 M4SSD2
- 2 TB HDD

Comment: This is only slightly more clear then the last time you posted this.  What exactly is the setup you are trying to achieve?  Why would you RAID the SSD and HDD?   Which SSD did you RAID with the HDD?  You're better off going back to the old question, cleaning it up and requesting it be reopened, rather than just reporting the same not-very-complete question.

Comment: This is a re-post of the same user's original question which was closed: [Can I use Intel RST caching on another (i.e. non-OS) hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/522793/can-i-use-intel-rst-caching-on-another-i-e-non-os-hard-drive), but that being said, I believe we should re-open the original.

Comment: i editd the last one..how can i make a requst?